# sort fileinfo list by int within fileinfo name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, fileinfo

I have some trouble to sort a List, I need it to be sorted by the FileInfo.Name attribut, within this name is an interger with unknown length at the very beginning of the string. I need to sort the list by this number.

As my experience it is very difficult to compare two strings by a number within this string, so I could need some help.

This is my list:

[image]

I need the list to be sorted from this [1,13,2,3,4,5] into this [1,2,3,4,5,13]

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
infos.Sort((a, b) => a.Split('-')[0].CompareTo(b.Split('-')[0]));
```

Of course this can not work as I try to compare strings by numbers....

**EDIT:**
Unfortunaely the solution from Mukund does not work as shown in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
infos.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[0]))


class Program11
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            var infos = new List<string> { "1-100.jpg", "13-11.jpg", "2-145.jpg", "3-421.jpg", "4-842.jpg", "5-1000.jpg" };

            var orderedList = infos.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('-')[0]));

            foreach (var lstItem in orderedList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lstItem);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: there is a little mistake in your answer: infos.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Name.Split('-')[0])); but it does not work anyway ;D

Comment: what is that @user3868224?

Comment: "x.Name.Split" and as I said I already tried it, unfortunately your solution does not sort anything

Comment: @user3868224 now check the answer. Is this what you aren't looking for?

Comment: Your updated solution just work for List<string>! It does not work with List<FileInfo>!

Comment: I didn't change anything solution. Variable infos seems list of string to me. So I gave this solution. FileInfo.Name attribute is I guess of type string so. you can use this property in orderby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110507/discussion-between-user3868224-and-mukund).